# Jquery image matching game

Tags: jquery, counter

I am looking for a solution to a game I am building for a class Im taking at O'Reilly School of Technology.

To play this game, you turn over two cards at a time and if they match, you win 2 points; if they don't match, you lose a point. If the images match, those cards stay turned over; if they don't match, the cards are placed face down again so you can't see what's on them. The trick is to remember where each card is so you can match!

At the completion of the game, every image in the board will be visible, and you will display the points in an alert for the user:

I have the game fairly close to complete but I am stuck on how to add 2 points to the score if the images match and if they do match then the stay visible. If I could implement the scoring feature I will just about have it. Any help would be great. Here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jmccommas/7EzBX/1/ and the code is below. I appreciate everyones time on this.

jquery code:

```
        var lastSelected;
    $(function(){
        addImg();
        start();
        click();
        check();
    });

    function check(el){
        var score = 0;
        if($(lastSelected).attr("src") == $(el).find("img").attr("src") && $(lastSelected).hasClass("visible")) {
                score++;
                alert("Congradulation! You scored!!" + " " + score + " Points");


        }
        lastSelected = $(el).find("img");
        clearAll();

    }

    var score = function(){

    };   

    function start(){
        $("div.row div img").addClass("hidden");
    };

    function click(){
        $("div.row div").each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
             if($("img", this).hasClass("hidden")){
                $("img",this).removeClass("hidden");
                $("img",this).addClass("visible");
                 check($(this));

             }else if($("img",this).hasClass("visible")){
                $("img",this).removeClass("visible");
                $("img",this).addClass("hidden");
             }

            });

        });

    };

    // add Random Images
    function addImg (){

        var images = ["http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/cheese.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/eggs.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_blender.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/tea.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_collander.gif","http://efreeman.userworld.com/jQuery/images/kitchen_teapot.gif"];

    var imagesused = [];
    $('.container div:not(.row)').each(function() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
        $(this).append('<img src="' + images[rand] + '"/>');
        if (imagesused.indexOf(images[rand]) != -1) images.splice(rand, 1);
        else imagesused.push(images[rand]);
        console.log(images);

    });
    }
    // Clear the images Button
    var clearAll = function(){
        $(':button').click(function() {
        $('div.row div img').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
        });

    };
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>jQuery: Manipulating and Traversing Elements Project</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
        div.container, div.row, form {
          clear: both;
        }
        div.row > div {
          position: relative;
          float: left;
          width: 100px;
          height: 170px;
          padding: 30px;
          margin: 10px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px grey;
          vertical-align: bottom;
        }
        div.row > div > img {
          display: inline-block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          bottom: 30px;
        }
        .visible {
          visibility: visible;
        }
        .hidden {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
        .done {
          visibility: visible;
        }
      </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="game.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form>
        <input type="button" value="Play again">
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just wanted to point something out:  After you call `Check()` you are calling `clearAll();` which causes which adds a class of `hidden` to all the images.  This is part of your problem.

Comment: The clearall() function only runs when the pay again button is clicked. That shouldn't effect the game tough

Comment: I noticed when I clicked one of the divs, clearAll was being called every time.  When I commented it out, the images stayed, but you don't want that either.

Comment: Makes sense, I moved the clearAll function below the function check(el){

Comment: I found the solution which can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmccommas/AhPfV/